# Extjs paging toolbar with grid panel not working

Tags: gridview, extjs, paging

I have the below code for paging in extjs... Even though I set it as 5 records per page, it still shows 6... and page 1 of 2 does not show "1"... I had problem with data from sql [Click here to go that Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235286/how-to-page-data-according-to-pagingtoolbars-request).... so I decided to try out with memory store... but I still don't get the paging right.... any help?

```
    constructor: function () {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        pageSize: 5,
        storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
        fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
        data: {
            'totalCount': "6",
            'items': [{
                'name': 'Lisa',
                "email": "lisa@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-111-1224"
            }, {
                'name': 'Bart',
                "email": "bart@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-222-1234"
            }, {
                'name': 'Homer',
                "email": "home@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-222-1244"
            }, {
                'name': 'Marge',
                "email": "marge@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-222-1254"
            }, {
                'name': '29',
                "email": "marge@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-222-1254"
            }, {
                'name': '30',
                "email": "marge@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-222-1254"
        }]
    },
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items',
            totalProperty: 'totalCount'
        }
    }
});

this.grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    disableSelection: true,
    loadMask: true,
    stripeRows: true,
    trackover: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

    store: store,
    columns: [{
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name'
    }, {
        text: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email'
    }, {
        text: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone'
    }],


    bbar: Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
        store: store,
        displayInfo: true,
        displayMsg: 'Displaying Surveys {0} - {1} of {2}',
        emptyMsg: "No Surveys to display"
    })


});
grid.loadPage(1);
}
```

}
});

Comment: try adding an id property to the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory proxy wont work with a regular paging mechanics.  You need a special user extension classes: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Paging Scroll down to "Paging with Local Data" section.

Comment: Thanks dbrin... I knew I had to look for paging with local data, but assumed it would be different if I used static data.